# what is the equivalent of input type="hidden" in vuetify

Tags: forms, vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

i have this dialog, and i want to hide the index to not be shown to the user .
so i want to make something like input="hidden" but i don't know how.

i want to get the value of the index input to update my data but i don't want to be appeared to user as field of the form

```
  <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog1"
      width="500">
     
      <v-btn   large  slot="activator" :ripple="false" style=" background-color:green;color:white;" @click="addplus">Ajouter une regle</v-btn>
     
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">{{formTitle}}</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container grid-list-md>
            
            <v-layout wrap>
            
              <v-flex xs12>
       
               <v-text-field label="nom de la regle *"   v-model="nom" required> </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex xs12>
               <v-text-field label="regle *"  v-model="regle" required> </v-text-field>

             </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12>
               <v-text-field label="index *"  v-model="index" required> </v-text-field>

             </v-flex>
              
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
          <small>*indicates required field</small>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat  @click="close()">fermer</v-btn>
            <v-btn v-if="editedIndex===-1" type="button" @click="addClick"
        class="btn btn-primary">
        Ajouter
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn v-else type="button" @click="update"
        class="btn btn-primary">
        Modifier
        </v-btn>
          
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

Comment: If you are going to make that input as hidden then i think you can remove that input itself from the DOM as it does not make any sense to make that hidden. Instead, you can pass the index value from the data object directly.

Comment: v-model doesn't work on hidden input. You can use
<input type="hidden" :value="someData" >
reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1194

Comment: The equivalent of `<input type="hidden">` in vuetify is `<input type="hidden">`. Since it doesn't render, you don't need a `<v-input>`. Use `:value` to bind it to a component prop/data. You don't need `v-model` with it, since there's no user interaction, hence it should only have one way binding.